# Post big data through HTTP protocol

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

ASP.NET Core MVC 2

I need to send the binary data to server. Data size often can be big but not more than 1 Gb. This is my attempt to do it:

```
var client = new HttpClient();

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
{
    fs.Position = 0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[fs.Length];
    fs.Read(bytes, 0, (int) fs.Length);

    ByteArrayContent content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);
    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    content.Headers.ContentLength = fs.Length;

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost:5000/Home/Upload");
    request.Content = content;

    try
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        Console.WriteLine("Response status code: {0}", response.StatusCode);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", ex.Message);
    }
}
```

In the debug mode I try to send 27Mb data. In the row

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

the breakpoint works, but after this nothing happen: the breackpoints for

```
Console.WriteLine("Response status code: {0}", response.StatusCode);
```

and

```
Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", ex.Message);
```

don't work. Application silently finished.

What I did wrong?

Comment: are you receiving data at the server side?

Comment: No, the breakpoint of my controller doesn't work at this case. But if I post the same file via Postman program then server receives it and controller's breakpoint works. I don't understand this difference of behaviour.

Comment: may be you need to wait for response

Comment: something like

  var task= Task.Run(async () =>
                    {
                        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
                        Console.WriteLine("Response status code: {0}", response.StatusCode);
                    });
                    task.Wait();

Comment: @RudreshaParameshappa Pay attantion that I do it via `await`. Am I right?

Comment: oh sorry I am testing scenario in .net 4.5 thats why my main method is not async

Comment: I can share my code source if it is necessary for this problem solving. I use JetBrains Rider 2018.1 EAP in Linux Mint 18.3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167804/discussion-between-rudresha-parameshappa-and-andrey-bushman).

Comment: *Don't* buffer data in memory. Don't use ByteArrayContent. Use StreamContent so the data is copied directly to the server from the source stream.

Comment: @AndreyBushman checkout this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40044468/differences-in-streamcontent-and-bytearraycontent-webapi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use `ByArrayContent`, just use `StreamContent` with `PostAsync`.

remove following code

```
fs.Position = 0;
byte[] bytes = new byte[fs.Length];
fs.Read(bytes, 0, (int) fs.Length);

ByteArrayContent content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes);
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
content.Headers.ContentLength = fs.Length;

var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost:5000/Home/Upload");
request.Content = content;

try
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

Replace with below code as `HttpClient` contains `PostAsync` we can use

```
try
{
     HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:5000/Home/Upload", new StreamContent(fs));
```